# Permissions totally messed up - Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows, permissions, uac

I totally messed up my user permissions as I keep getting an 'Access Denied System 5 error" at a command prompt. In my stupidity, I just started changing all the 'user/mycomputer' permissions thru UAC - when I started this, of course, **I was asked do I want to continue** - I said '**YES**' and proceeded to click away - then I started running into the 'Access denied' and something about 'inconsistencies' and how I could mess things up. I just want to get it back to the original state (when I bought computer).  My question is- I have several different discs - a Factory default backup(s) and a Windows 7 System Repair disc - which one of these will 'fix' permissions or will neither of these discs help? and if no, what are my alternatives?  Thanks

Lorelei

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your factory default backup disc should work fine.  The Windows 7 system repair disk will try to fix problems with Windows boot but won't systematically check for permission issues on the entire drive.

Alternatively, you could attempt to repair the permission issues by taking ownership of all files on the entire system (any local administrative account has permission to take ownership).  With ownership granted, you can then change your permissions to files and folders you now own.

An elevated command prompt and judicious use of takeown and icacls.exe will likely do the trick.  For example, here are a set of commands that will take ownership and give everyone (EVERYONE) access to all files and subfolders of the current command line path:

```
takeown.exe /F * /A /R /D Y
icacls.exe * /grant Everyone:(F) /grant Guests:(F) /grant Users:(F) /T /C /Q
```

Use it with caution -- obviously this will cause a security issue if used improperly, but if you want a quick fix to be able to use your existing system (make backups, etc.), this is likely where you should start.